# cakephp paginator helper shows error when delete the last record from the last page

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I just want to redirect that to the last index if the last record is deleted from the last page.
please help  me to do this.

```
<?php                       
    echo $this->Paginator->prev
      ($this->Html->image('prev.png'), array('escape' => false), 
    array(), null, array('class' => 'prev'));
    echo $this->Paginator->counter
      ('Page {:page} of {:pages}, Total Records {:count}');                     
    echo $this->Paginator->next($this->Html->image
      ('next.png'), array('escape' => false), 
        array(), null, array('class' => 'next'));
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of CakePHP 2.3 - [Out of Range page requests](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests) will throw an exception.

However the documentation is not correct in saying that the paging parameters will be available to you in $this->request->params['paging'], because those are defined *after* the exception is thrown. (*This problem has been fixed in CakePHP 2.4.x two months ago*)

So, to get the effect you want you can do something like this in your controller:

```php
public function index() {
    try {
        $paginatedData = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //get current page
        $page = $this->request->params['named']['page'];
        if( $page > 1 ){
            //redirect to previous page
            $this->redirect( array( "page" => $page-1 ) );
        }else{
            $paginatedData = array(); //no data to paginate so use empty array()
                                      //you will have to check for this in the view and no longer display the pagination links, since they will NOT be defined
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the URL for the first page and how many pages do you have?

Comment: Oh, can you please edit your question and post the code in the controller as well. The part that does the pagination and catches the exception?