# Show last page of paginated items in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination

If requesting for a page say page number 3 in paginated items of a table in cakephp,
which is having only 2 pages, how do we show the last page ie page number 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution here:-

[cakephp paginator helper shows error when delete the last record from the last page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421935/cakephp-paginator-helper-shows-error-when-delete-the-last-record-from-the-last-p)

```
public function index() {
    try {
        $paginatedData = $this->Paginator->paginate();
    } catch (NotFoundException $e) {
        //get current page
        $page = $this->request->params['named']['page'];
        if( $page > 1 ){
            //redirect to previous page
            $this->redirect( array( "page" => $page-1 ) );
        }else{
            $paginatedData = array(); //no data to paginate so use empty array()
                                      //you will have to check for this in the view and no longer display the pagination links, since they will NOT be defined
        }
    }
}
```